# MFC App closes on startup

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

Trying to run a simple MFC App but closes because the program terminates, assuming I need to run the dialog box in a seperate thread but can't work out how.

Here's the code so far:

```
CWinApp theApp;

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[])
{
    int nRetCode = 0;

    HMODULE hModule = ::GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    theApp.InitApplication();
    theApp.InitInstance();
    theApp.Run();

    AfxWinTerm();

    if (hModule != NULL)
    {
        // initialize MFC and print and error on failure
        if (!AfxWinInit(hModule, NULL, ::GetCommandLine(), 0))
        {
            // TODO: change error code to suit your needs
            _tprintf(_T("Fatal Error: MFC initialization failed\n"));
            nRetCode = 1;

        }
        else
        {
            MyDialog *mdlg = new MyDialog();
            mdlg->Create( IDD_MDLG, theApp.m_pMainWnd);
            mdlg->ShowWindow( true );

        }
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: change error code to suit your needs
        _tprintf(_T("Fatal Error: GetModuleHandle failed\n"));
        nRetCode = 1;
    }

    return nRetCode;
}
```

There must be something simple I can do to keep the program from terminating, just not sure how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling:

```
mdlg->ShowWindow( true );
```

you should do:

```
mdlg->DoModal();
```

Also, I dont think you need `Create`. If you want to stay with modeless dialog, then you should create message loop before returning from main - something like here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows

Comment: Was looking at that but my class (inherits from a CDialog) has no member "DoModel"?

Comment: If thats MFC CDialog then it surely does have DoModal (by inheritance): http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/619z63f5.aspx

Comment: Yeah I was being an idiot, I get a debug assertion failed:
// cannot call DoModal on a dialog already constructed as modeless
 ASSERT(m_hWnd == NULL);

Comment: Got rid of the create, but message pump assertation failed:
TRACE(traceAppMsg, 0, "Error: CWinThread::PumpMessage called when not permitted.\n");
   ASSERT(FALSE);

Comment: Finally got it; used you're wikipedia link and called WinMain after doing Create() and ShowWindow();

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see you created a Win32 Console Application and try to add a GUI to it? You should only do that if you really need the console. If not, then better create a new project, select the MFC Application template and choose dialog based application. The wizard will create all you need.

BTW, your

```
MyDialog *mdlg = new MyDialog();
mdlg->Create( IDD_MDLG, theApp.m_pMainWnd);
mdlg->ShowWindow( true );
```

should better have been:

```
MyDialog mdlg;
mdlg.DoModal();
```

No need for `new` in your case, so just allocate the object on the stack. And `DoModal` does what you want.

In my Win32 Console Application with MFC support I was able to show a dialog. But in my wizard generated code these lines were not present, so maybe you should delete them:

```
theApp.InitApplication();
theApp.InitInstance();
theApp.Run();

AfxWinTerm();
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I was going for, any idea why this could be coming up:
TRACE(traceAppMsg, 0, "Error: CWinThread::PumpMessage called when not permitted.\n"); ASSERT(FALSE); ?

Comment: @user3047190 When does that message come? Did you recreate the project or is this still the console application? When does the error occur?

Comment: Thanks, solved it using the wiki link in the accepted answer, I know the problem was something to do with message pumping so the wiki link allowed me to create a message loop to pass messages between the dialog buttons and the program - and by extension kept the program open

Comment: @user3047190 I updated my answer. There is no need to create a message loop!